# Send mail through Jenkins on Successful build?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, configuration, smtp

I have to configure SMTP server so that in Jenkins configuration path I can give the SMTP server.Can somebody tell how to configure SMTP server in Ubuntu and also how to map that server in Jenkins Email-Ext plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution as :-

1) sudo apt-get install mailutils (on Jenkins machine)

2) Install Email-ext plugin in Jenkins.

```
 Select Internet Site under Postfix configuration
 click on ok
 enter your system mail name(Default you can select)
 click on ok
```

3) Login in Jenkins server

4) Select Configuration under manage Jenkins

5) Go to E-mail Notification option.

6) In SMTP server option enter "localhost" without quotes.

7) In Default user e-mail suffix enter your email suffix.

8) check Test configuration by sending test e-mail option.

9) Enter your email-id.

10) click on test configuration.

11) check your email for confirmation

12) Now go to the project and select E-mail Notification under the Jenkins configuration project

13) enter E-mail id of the Recipients (separated by space for multiple recipients)

14) click on save.