# smtp.gmail.com is not accepted by jenkins email plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to mail my report to my team on a daily basis and thus am using email plugin for jenkins-1.555.
I can enter "smtp.gmail.com" as smtp server on my local machine and this works.
However when doing the same on Windows server,it does not accept this and shows a error "Unknown host name: smtp.gmail.com"

Please advise.

Comment: IPv4 vs IPv6 problem?

Comment: Please check the below answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691446/send-mail-through-jenkins-on-successful-build/32880503#32880503